# How to get the values of Check Box(@Html.CheckBox) through JQuery JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to bind values(checked or not) to a `@Html.CheckBox` in MVC 3 through JQuery.

This is my HTML-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Brands = ViewBag.GetBrands;
foreach (var item in Brands)
{
 @Html.CheckBox("Brands", false, new{value = item.Value});
 <label>@item.Text</label><br />
}}
```

This is what I tried-

```
function test {

    var url = "/OfficeManagement/Offices/GetOfficeConfiguration";
    var stringToReverse = rowData.ID;
    var noCache = Date();
    $.get(url, { officeID: stringToReverse, "noCache": noCache }, function (data) {
    for(int i=0;i<data.Configuration.OfficeBrands.count;i++)
         {
          $('#Brands').attr('checked', data.Configuration.OfficeBrands[i]);
         }
    ...............
   }
```

Comment: Seems like there will be multiple checkboxes. So put your HTML in a container ( a div or something like that ) then loop through all the checkboxes inside that div.

Comment: yes multiple check boxes. Its already inside a `<td>`

Comment: So inside that javascript function, loop through each checkbox and assign the attribute.

Comment: I hope i did the same

Comment: No.. you are looping through the data , not through the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me-

```
$.each(data.Configuration.OfficeBrands, function(i, brand) {
$(':checkbox[Value="' + brand.ID + '"]').prop('checked', true);});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        **$("#Brands").attr("checked"," ")**
```

In the above line, you are accessing the checkbox using **ID**, but if there are multiple checkboxes having the same ID, then it will work only for the first checkbox. So, add a class attribute to all the checkboxes and then access them using the class.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you can try as follows,

Create checkbox with the unique name as follows:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (var item in Brands)
{
     @Html.CheckBox("Brands" + counter, false, new{value = item.Value});
     counter++;
 }
```

It will create html markup somewhat similar like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "Brands0" />
<input type="checkbox" name = "Brands1" />
<input type="checkbox" name = "Brands2" />
```

Then in jquery you can retrive the values like this:

```
   for(int i=0;i<data.Configuration.OfficeBrands.count;i++)
   {
      $( "input[name*='"Brands"+i+"]"').attr('checked', data.Configuration.OfficeBrands[i]);
   }
```